# Solution to diamond inheritance, but is it appropriate?

Tags: c++, virtual-inheritance, diamond-problem

Aside from the other various things I've been working on, I've also been making an image api. One problem I've encountered though is the need for there to be an image base class that contains the dimensions of the image. From it would branch ImageIn and ImageOut, and from those come ImageIO. Here was my original solution;

```
class ImageBase{
public:
  point<int> Dim() const=0;
};

class ImageI : virtual public ImageBase{
public:
  virtual unsigned int get(int x, int y) const=0;
};

class ImageO : virtual public ImageBase{
public:
  virtual void set(int x, int y, unsigned int col)=0;
};

class ImageIO : public ImageI, public ImageO{
};

class Bitmap : public ImageIO{
  ...
};
```

Of course, now their are two vtable pointers and dims to each instance of image, and I suppose given the size of an array of pixels, it's probably not worth worrying about, but there is something ascetically displeasing about this, so I purpose this solution;

```
class ImageIO{ // could also be called ImageBase
public:
  point<int> Dim() const=0;
  virtual unsigned int get(int x, int y) const=0;
  virtual void set(int x, int y, unsigned int col)=0;
};

class ImageI : public ImageIO{
public:
  point<int> Dim() const=0;
  virtual unsigned int get(int x, int y) const=0;
private:
  virtual void set(int x, int y, unsigned int col)=0;
};

class ImageO : public ImageIO{
public:
  point<int> Dim() const=0;
  virtual void set(int x, int y, unsigned int col)=0;
private:
  virtual unsigned int get(int x, int y) const=0;
};

class Bitmap : public ImageIO{
  ...
};
```

Now, because certain operators in ImageO and ImageI are private, they cannot be accessed from a pointer of that type, accomplishing pretty much what having an input and output edition of a class accomplishes. There is a slight issue though, the casting syntax is now somewhat more complex.

```
ImageI* myImgInput = static_cast<ImageI*>((ImageIO*)(&myReal));
```

I'm thinking some clever use of casting functions can make the process automatic, so the final question is, are there any inherent flaws in this? I've tested it with a minor implementation, and it works fully, but I'd hate to get the api done, then have to start over.

### Edit

Note that what was ImageBase in the second example is now ImageIO for the sake of clarity, and that ImageI and ImageO in the second example **were not** supposed to virtually inherit from ImageIO

Comment: the edit is a second question and should likely be removed and asked as a new question

Comment: Note that the classes in the second example were never supposed to use virtual inheritance.

Comment: It looked like the original solution was better and more correct.

Comment: How so? The second solution is half the size, and can contain all the functionality of the first. What is the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**This cannot work if the bases have data members**

Using the following sizes

```
Imagaebase=4
ImageI=12 + 4 from Imagebase
ImageO=24 + 4 from Imagebase
```

In the first example the size of `Bitmap` would be 4 + 12 + 24 (Note Imagebase only counts once) = 40

In the second case the size of `Bitmap` would be 4

Casting would not work if the sizes are so askew

**If there is no data in any of the classes then:**

The Base should be `ImageIO` and have all functions in it

Then have `ImageI` and `ImageO` inherit from it to make the not allowed function(s) to be private.  Then there is no casting needed.

This would look like the following:

```
class ImageIO{
public:
  point<int> Dim() const=0;
  virtual unsigned int get(int x, int y) const=0;
  virtual void set(int x, int y, unsigned int col)=0;
};

class ImageI : virtual public ImageIO{
private:
  virtual void set(int x, int y, unsigned int col)
  {
        // Can't be called
  }
};

class ImageO : virtual public ImageIO{
private:
  virtual unsigned int get(int x, int y) const
  {
        // Can't be called
  }
};

class Bitmap : public ImageIO{
  ...
};
```

Comment: I don't follow, why would ImageO be larger then ImageI? Neither of them contain data, they only declare functions, and being that their inheritance is similar, I should think they would both have the same width?

Comment: I just compiled the code here with -fdump-class-hierarchy, and the .class file states the class ImageIO for the first example to be only 8 bytes wide, and the version from the second example to be only four bytes wide. What  do you mean by 40 bytes wide?

Comment: @user4578093  You did not make it clear that the base classes **have** to have no data, see the edit for a solution in the case where they don't

Comment: This is exactly the state of things in the second example. ImageO -> ImageBase,   ImageI -> ImageBase,   Bitmap -> ImageBase

Comment: So, are you in agreement with the structure?

Comment: @user4578093  yes, with the subtle clarification that the base is ImageIO, see the last edit

Comment: ImageBase is ImageIO, but I'll change the name to clarify.

Comment: Are you satisfied with the answer?

Comment: Thank you for the second opinion